# In Python, is there a simple way to print a string given a list of characters with using str.join() method

Tags: python, string, list, printing

Is there a simple way to print a string out of a list of characters without using `str.join()` method?

For example, I have a list of chars:

```
li = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

I want to get `'Hello'` printed out
**without** using `str.join()` method:

```
print(''.join(li))
```

Comment: how much simpler could/should it be? `''.join(li)` looks very simple to me...

Comment: Isn't `''.join(li)` simple ?

Comment: homework, kind of. no join or for loop.

Comment: @oeyh I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for c in li:
    print(c, end='')
```

If you are not allow to use `for`, try this:

```
print(*li, sep = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a serious answer to this bad question, but I can't resist posting it.

```
>>> li = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> reduce(str.__add__, li)
'Hello'
>>>
>>> str(bytearray(li))
'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

**print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)**

specify end="" instead of end="\n".

So this should work

```
li=['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
for l in li:
    print(l,end="")
```

for further details about print function type

```
help(print)
```

in your terminal